# Summing up this "factorial series"??

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, number-theory, divergent-series

Ok so the series $k.k!$ can be summed up by writing $k$ as $k+1-1$, breaking the terms up and then adding. But if we take the sum of this series uptil infinity, it comes out to be $-1!$ = $-1$(Everything cancels). What I really can't get a grip on is HOW is this possible. Every consecutive term increases considering that we have a factorial term in there I think it's safe to say that it increases a LOT. So shouldn't this series diverge? Something like :

$\dfrac{1}{1.2.3} + \dfrac{2}{2.3.4} \dots$ is still understandable. Each term decreases and as the no of terms approaches a bigger value, the terms become very small and the series converges. But what about this factorial series? Is this some wizard level thing like what Ramanujan came up with, proving the sum of all natural nos to be equal to $\dfrac{-1}{12}$? Or something simpler?Pls try and refrain from using anything above 12th grade.

Thanks!!

Comment: Could you show how you derive $-1!=-!$ by taking the sum to infinity?

Comment: I cannot see how one can get anything else than infinity in the limit.

Comment: The series $1!-2!+3!- \cdots \pm k! \cdots$ can be treated by methods of divergent summation and gets some finite value meaningfully assigned in terms of the exponential-integral function if I recall correctly. This can even be extended to the nonalternating series. So I think, there should be a similar approach for the series in question. (I've added the tag `divergent-series` ). *Recommendation:* surely you should take a trip through wikipedia's "divergent-series" entries and improve the text of your question to make the scope of your question better visible.

Comment: @Théophile Every subsequent term just keeps on cancelling??

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Every subsequent term just keeps on cancelling??

Comment: If I understand right, you're saying that all the terms cancel except the $-1!$, so you end up with $-1$. It's true that the terms do cancel, but you need to look at the partial sum at every step:
$$2!-1!\\
3!-1!\\
4!-1!\\
\cdots\\
n!-1!\\
\cdots$$
At every step, there's still an $n!$ term present. Sure, it gets cancelled in the next step, but it's replaced by $(n+1)!$.

Answer (score 3):

$$k\cdot k! = (k + 1 - 1)\cdot k! = (k+1)! - k!$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot k! = (n+1)! - 1$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\cdot k! = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot k! = \infty$$
**Nothing** cancels when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: So where am I going wrong when I write it as : $2! - 1! + 3! - 2! + 4! - 3! + 5! - 4! \dots$. Now the first term for one value of $k$ gets cancelled by the second term for $k+1$. Till a finite value, it would be $(n+1)! - 1$ but when we have an infinite no of terms doesn't every term just keeps on cancelling. Isn't this how we calculate the sum of such series till infinite terms? I am a bit confused here...

Comment: @Pranav, the sum of a series is *by definition* the limit of the sequence of partial sums.

Comment: @Pranav I've been wondering how you got $-1!$, now I know. You can try your method with $1-1+1-1+1-\ldots$ in two ways (getting either $0$ or $1$) to see that this doesn't work. Marting-Blas Pereze Pinilla mentioned the right definition to work with.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Ohh kk thanks. I guess I got the definition messed up.